# Edit Frame with button within Frame

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a MainWindow, wich Contain a Frame.
My Frame switches between different xaml's using buttons on my MainWindow.
the problem I have now, is that I need to do this also from buttons within the xaml loaded within my Frame.
i tried te following:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            Page myPage = new Page();

            mw.editFramePage(myPage);

        }
```

here is my edit editFramePage Method:

```
public void editFramePage(Page page)
        {
            myFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(page, UriKind.Relative);
        }
```

This works, however it pops up a new MainWindow, I want this withing my current MainWindow.
Could use some help!

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a **new** `MainWindow`.  You need to keep a reference to the original `MainWindow` and call `editFramePage` on that.

Comment: Please give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new `MainWindow`. You need to keep a reference to the original `MainWindow` and call `editFramePage` on that.

The default implementation skeleton of a WPF application saves the main window in `App.MainWindow`.  To get to it, you need to use `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

So your function should look like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;
    Page myPage = new Page();

    mw.editFramePage(myPage);
}
```

Note that the cast to `MainWindow` is required because `Application.MainWindow` returns the type `Window` instead of the more-specific type that you need.